# Mspec notation algebra

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In commutative algebra, given a ring A, what does the notation $m-spec(A)$ stand for?

Comment: the set of all maximal ideal with zarisky topology

Comment: I think i've seen it used nonstandardly for the spectrum of minimal ideals once before, too.  it should be abundantly clear from context in any case.